# How can I downgrade CUDA from 12.0 to 11.8 via command line?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I use Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with an NVIDIA A100 40GB GPU and CUDA 12.0. How can I downgrade CUDA from 12.0 to 11.8 via command line?